# Comparing 2 arrays and modifying 1

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

Ok, assume that I have 2 arrays.

> $myArray = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10');
>   $badNumbers = ('3', '6', '10')

What I want to do is compare `$myArrays` with `$badNumbers`, then modify `$myArrays` to remove anything found in the `$badNumbers`.

So after some code, the end result would be:

> $myArray = ('1', '2', '4', '5', 7', '8', '9');
>   $badNumbers = ('3', '6', '10')

Is there anyway to do this? I've of some things, but nothing seems to work. The comparing part alone I already have some problems.

EDIT: I'm fine with a third array too. Something along the line of for each value, if it doesn't appear in the second array, `array_push` to the new array. But I'm still not so sure on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_diff` to get the result.

```
$myArray= array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'); 
$badNumbers= array('3','6','0');
$available = array_diff($myArray, $badNumbers);

print_r($available);

echo '<br /><br />' . implode(', ', $available);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. How did I miss this page in the PHP Manual, I'd never know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_diff($myArray, $badNumbers);
echo count($result) ? 'there were differences' : 'there werent';
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What does "count" do? Is "echo" like "print"?

```
echo count($result) ? 'there were differences' : 'there werent';
```